# Can a receptacle before a light or light switch use a pigtail?

Tags: wiring

Can a receptacle before a light or light switch use a pigtail or does it have to have the black and white wires on each side of the receptacle?

Answer (score 3):

It can use a pigtail, unless it's a GFCI receptacle **and** you want the light to have GFCI protection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can use a pigtail as long as the pigtail fits the application you are able to do so.